# How do I make my Java Sudoku solver faster for more input?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, sudoku

```
public class Solver {

    public LinkedList<Sudoku> sudokus = new LinkedList<>();

    public Solver() {
        Sudoku current = null;
        int count = 1;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("p096_sudoku.txt")))) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                if (line.contains("Grid")) {
                    current = new Sudoku(count);
                    sudokus.add(current);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    current.addLine(line);
                }
            }
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Solver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    /*
    For debugging purposes
    */
    public void SolveFirstPrint() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Sudoku s : sudokus) {
            if (count == 0) {
                s.lines = solve(s.lines);
                if (s.lines != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

                            System.out.print(s.lines[i][j] + " ");
                        }
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
            count++;

        }
    }
    public void SolveFirst() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Sudoku s : sudokus) {
            if (count == 0) {
                s.lines = solve(s.lines);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    

    
    public void SolveAllPrint() {
        for (Sudoku s : sudokus) {
            s.lines = solve(s.lines);

        }
        for (Sudoku s : sudokus) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    System.out.print(s.lines[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public void SolveAll() {

        for (Sudoku s : sudokus) {
            s.lines = solve(s.lines);

        }
    }

    public static boolean check(int[] numbers) {
        int[][] key = new int[2][numbers.length];
        key[0] = numbers;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            key[1][i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > 0) {
                key[1][numbers[i] - 1]++;
            }
        }
        boolean keycheck = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (key[1][i] > 1) {
                keycheck = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (keycheck == true) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static boolean checkY(int[][] numbers, int y) {
        int[] key = new int[numbers[y].length];
        key = numbers[y];
        return check(key);
    }

    public static boolean checkX(int[][] numbers, int x) {
        int[] key = new int[numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            key[i] = numbers[i][x];
        }
        return check(key);
    }

    public static boolean checkAll(int[][] numbers) {
        
        //Check Y lijnen
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (!checkY(numbers, i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //Check X lijnen
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (!checkX(numbers, i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Check of alle boxes nog kloppen
        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 0, 2, 0, 2)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 0, 2, 3, 5)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 0, 2, 6, 8)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 3, 5, 0, 2)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 3, 5, 3, 5)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 3, 5, 6, 8)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 6, 8, 0, 2)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 6, 8, 3, 5)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkSquare(numbers, 6, 8, 6, 8)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean checkSquare(int[][] numbers, int minX, int maxX, int minY, int maxY) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int j = minY; j < maxY +1; j++) {
            for (int i = minX; i < maxX +1; i++) {
                if (numbers[j][i] != 0) {
                    // Als de hashmap al dezelfde key heeft in deze box
                    if (myMap.containsKey(numbers[j][i])) {
                        // Kan het huidige nummer niet ingevoerd worden, dus false.
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        // Voeg nummer toe
                        myMap.put(numbers[j][i], 1);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] numbers) {
        // Controlleer of er wel een grid van 9x9 is
        if (numbers.length != 9 || numbers[0].length != 9) {
            return false;
        }
        return (checkAll(numbers));
    }

    public static int[][] solve(int[][] numbers) {
        int[] freeslot = getNext(numbers);
        int f1 = freeslot[0];
        int f2 = freeslot[1];
        if (f1 == -1) {
            return numbers;
        }
        numbers = recurseSolve(f1, f2, numbers);
        return numbers;
    }

    public static int[][] recurseSolve(int yNR, int xNR, int[][] numbers) {
        int[][] solved;
        
        int[][] copy = new int[numbers.length][numbers[0].length];
        for (int y = 0; y < numbers.length; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < numbers[0].length; z++) {
                copy[y][z] = numbers[y][z];
            }
        }
        // Als t valid is doorgaan met next solven.
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            copy[yNR][xNR] = i;
            boolean valide = isValid(copy);
            if (valide) {
                
                solved = solve(copy);
                if (solved != null) {
                    return solved;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static int[] getNext(int[][] numbers) {
        int[] slot = {-1, -1};
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if (numbers[i][j] == 0) {
                    slot[0] = i;
                    slot[1] = j;
                    return slot;
                }
            }
        }
        return slot;
    }

    public int EulerSum() {
        int total = 0;
        for (Sudoku sudoku : sudokus) {
            total += sudoku.TopLeftNrs();
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Hi guys!

I made the above sudoku solver, but I have a problem.

I made the performance test below:

```
@Test
public void speedTest(){
    solver = new Solver();
    long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    solver.SolveFirst();
    long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
    double elapsedSeconds = tDelta / 1000.0;
    System.out.println("1 Sudoku: " +elapsedSeconds);
    solver = new Solver();
    long tStart2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    solver.SolveAll();
    long tEnd2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long tDelta2 = tEnd2 - tStart2;
    double elapsedSeconds2 = tDelta2 / 1000.0;
    System.out.println("50 Sudokus:"+elapsedSeconds2);
    }

    
}
```

And I get these results:

> Testsuite: InputTest
>
> 1 Sudoku: 0.014 sec
>
> 50 Sudokus, try 0: 7.314 sec

How is it possible that 1 sudoku is so fast but more than 1 gives me not a linear performance result?

Should I use something else than a Int[][]?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you got lucky w/ the first one.

Comment: I think @ScottHunter is right, if you use backtracking then the times can vary extremely because the number of wrong paths that are evaluated can potentially get quite large. And if you always copy the board this can take some time, better take back the wrong moves, it's a lot faster.

Comment: I'll look into that, smart thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I've only had a glance at your code/question, but it looks like your solver is just your bog standard bruteforce Sudoku solver. It also looks like you are reading Sudokus from an input file (which you haven't included).

A potential reason is this: Not all the 50 sudokus are the same and thus take a different amount of time to solve. Since your code checks for some magic "Grid" in the input file.

Bruteforce solvers on Sudoku are not the most efficient way to solve Sudoku; people have made certain inputs that make them take a long time.

That's my guess anyway. You could add timings inside your solver to see which ones take a long time.

Also your solveFirst method needlessly iterates the entire collection of puzzles; why not just get the first one and pass it to solve?

Comment: It's not brute-force, it's back-tracking, because it's checking all numbers until there is a violation, it doesn't generate each possible sudoku and checks if it is the solution.

Comment: "brute force" and "backtracking" are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Back-tracking is just a form of brute force no? It just defines the algorithm being used I thought.
My point I was trying to make (probably badly) is not every puzzle takes the same time to solve and some are created to make algorithms like back-tracking take a longer time. So perhaps if you have N puzzles and they are all different, you can just get the times for each to work out if there are specific puzzles that are slow.